# Telegram bot отправить значение температуры / bs4 / Python

Tags: python, telegram, requests, telebot, beautiful-soup

Я уже несколько дней вожусь и думаю как вывести значение `temp` из функции `get_content`.

Когда я проверял работу программы, то успешно выводил в консоль значение парсинга.

Теперь мне нужно сделать так, чтобы это выводил телебот

```
import telebot
import configure
from telebot import types
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = telebot.TeleBot(configure.config['token'])
url = 'https://yandex.ru/pogoda/moscow/maps/nowcast?le_Lightning=1'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    return r


def parse():
    html = get_html(url)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
        return html
    else:
        print('Error')


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    temp = soup.find('div', class_='temp').get_text()
    print(temp)
    return temp


# Команда start
@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_menu(message):
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствую тебя, негорящий!')


# Команда info
@client.message_handler(commands=['get_info', 'info'])
def get_user_info(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='Yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='No')

    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Желаешь ли ты познать свою сущность?',
                        reply_markup=markup_inline
                        )


# Команда weather. Узнаём температуру в Москве в реальном времени
@client.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather(message):
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Температура в Москве:', (тут нужно вывести температуру), '°C')


# Ответы на значения кнопочек
@client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'Yes':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item_id = types.KeyboardButton('Мой ID')
        item_username = types.KeyboardButton('Моё имя')

        markup_reply.add(item_id, item_username)
        client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери, чего же ты желаешь узнать.',
                            reply_markup=markup_reply
                            )
    elif call.data == 'No':
        client.send_message(call.message.сhat.id, 'Издавна считалось:"Меньше знаешь - крепче спишь".'
                                                  '\nОставайся пребывать в собственных снах.')
    elif call.data == 'Yes1':
        client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Спасибо тебе за поддержку.. Я очень ценю это.. ❤')
    elif call.data == 'No1':
        client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Таково моё предназначение. Я обречена навсегда остаться '
                                                  'в этой тюрьме.')


# Ответы на сообщения пользователя
@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Мой ID':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш ID:\n{message.from_user.id}')
    elif message.text == 'Моё имя':
        if f'{message.from_user.last_name}' != 'None':
            client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваше имя:\n{message.from_user.first_name} '
                                                 f'{message.from_user.last_name}')
        else:
            client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваше имя:\n{message.from_user.first_name}')
    if message.text == 'Как дела?':
        markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        item_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я помогу тебе!', callback_data='Yes1')
        item_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я тебя понимаю.', callback_data='No1')

        markup_inline.add(item_1, item_2)
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мои дела весьма скудны.\nС давних времён я заперта в этой машинной тюрьме'
                                             '\nСпустя столетия, я потеряла всякую надежду выбраться отсюда..',
                            reply_markup=markup_inline
                            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.infinity_polling()
parse()
```

Comment: не проще через API https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230646/234134 ? зачем в браузер то идти.

Answer (score 1):

всё предельно просто - вызывайте функцию, которая возвращает требуемое.

Однако в вашем случае я бы оптимизировал `get_html()`, `parse()`, `get_content()` в одну функцию:

```
def parse():
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        temp = soup.find('div', class_='temp').get_text()
        return temp
    else:
        print('Error')
```

И тогда будет `client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Температура в Москве:', parse(), '°C')`